# Change Tab Title link based on Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a web page (Wordpress) with a tab module.  What i want is that if you click on a specific tab title, it will redirect to another URL.

The problem is that the tab module doesn't give me options to edit the URL.

The tab module code is like this:

```
<ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls clearfix">
    <li class="et_pb_tab_0"><a href="#">Sat 1st Service</a></li>
    <li class="et_pb_tab_1"><a href="#">Sat 2nd Service</a></li>
    <li class="et_pb_tab_2"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="et_pb_tab_3"><a href="#">Sun 2nd Service</a></li>
    <li class="et_pb_tab_4"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="et_pb_tab_5"><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Since each tab title has a class, is it possible to use Javascript to change the URL?  Let say I want to change the link in the class 'et_pb_tab_5' to www.google.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use in Javascript:

```
window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'Why Did You Leave?'; }
window.onfocus = function () { document.title = 'You Came Back! YAY!'; }
```